# Ping mydomain.example returns Unknown host & dig +short mydomain.example - return nothing

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a Google Cloud DNS not responding to an IP mapping.

[image]

`ping mydomain.example` returns Unknown host

`dig +short mydomain.example` - returns nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It most likely looks like that the NS records not updated has caused the Cloud DNS to not activate.

You need to log in to your current providers domain administration console and change the NS records to:

- `ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com.`
- `ns-cloud-c2.googledomains.com.`
- `ns-cloud-c3.googledomains.com.`
- `ns-cloud-c4.googledomains.com.`

Once you configure them on your third party domain provider, whatever DNS records you have configured on Google Cloud DNS will take over. As long as you don't perform this change, Google Cloud DNS will not engage.